# NSMutableArray true convert to json output and post it to remote with Alamofire in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, post, swift3

I have `NSMutableArray` codes from `CoreData` and I want convert it to Json Array and post it to remote With `Alamofire`, I try to convert myArray to `jsonArray` but dont do true. My codes under below.

```
           let maras = try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Manager]

  if maras.count > 1 {

                let prod: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
                let prodArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

                for i in 0 ..< maras {
                    let a = maras[i]
                    prod.setValue(a.val1, forKey: "val1")
                    prod.setValue(a.val2, forKey: "val2")
                    prod.setValue(a.val3, forKey: "val3")
                    prod.setValue(a.val4, forKey: "val4")
                    prodArray.add(prod)
                }

               print(prodArray)   // OUTOUT UNDER BELOW
```

Under below Output `prodArray` wrong `json`

```
(
        {
        val1 = "2324";
        val2 = "1212";
        val3 = 234;
        val4 = "234234";
    },
        {
        val1 = "223324";
        val2 = "12232312";
        val3 = 233242344;
        val4 = "234223423434";
    }
)
```

must be valid `JSON` like under below. ( Also I have `SwiftyJson` in my project)

```
[{
    "val1": "2324",
    "val2": "1212",
    "val3": 234,
    "val4": "234234"
}, {
    "val1": "223324",
    "val2": "12232312",
    "val3": 233242344,
    "val4": "234223423434"
}]
```

After that I want to post my `prodArray` to remote with `Alamofire`.My codes under below

```
  Alamofire.request(Posturl, method: .post, parameters: prodArray, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
                .responseData{ response in
                   let success = json["status"]["type"].boolValue

                    if success == true {



            }

            }
```

Comment: @Eric ty but prodArray = params in alamofire line gives error dont accept it ?

Comment: i see json always as `[String,Any]`

Comment: this you can always add directly to alamofire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var json:[String:Any] = [:]


var jsonItem:[String:Any] = [:]

var jsonItemArray:[[String:Any]] = []

    jsonItem = [:]

    jsonItem["val1"] = "2324"
    jsonItem["val2"] = "1212"
    jsonItem["val3"] = 234
    jsonItem["val4"] = "234234"
    jsonItemArray.append(jsonItem)

    jsonItem = [:]
    jsonItem["val1"] = "223324"
    jsonItem["val2"] = "12232312"
    jsonItem["val3"] = 233242344
    jsonItem["val4"] = "234223423434"
    jsonItemArray.append(jsonItem)

print(jsonItemArray)

json["data"] = jsonItemArray

print(json)
```

> [["val2": "1212", "val3": 234, "val4": "234234", "val1": "2324"], ["val2": "12232312", "val3": 233242344, "val4": "234223423434", "val1": "223324"]]
>
> ["data": [["val2": "1212", "val3": 234, "val4": "234234", "val1": "2324"], ["val2": "12232312", "val3": 233242344, "val4": "234223423434", "val1": "223324"]]]

you should change your code to:

```
var prodArray:[[String:Any]] = []

for i in 0 ..< maras {
    let a = maras[i]

    let prod:[String:Any]
    prod["val1"] = a.val1
    prod["val2"] = a.val2
    prod["val3"] = a.val3
    prod["val4"] = a.val4
    prodArray.append(prod)
}
```

Comment: prodArray.add(prod) gives me ERROR : Value of type '[[String : Any]]' has no member 'add'

Comment: my first part of code  sample works in playground - can you post your exact definition of prodArray?

Comment: copy paste error - it should be `prodArray.append(prod)` - i edit my answer